# virtualenv without distutils

Tags: python, virtualenv, distutils

I'm copying a virtual environment created with `virtualenv venv` in a ubuntu wsl to another distro. After activating the venv in the new system, the command `pip3 --version` returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import getLogger
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

Apparently, distutils is not available in the environment. If I execute `sudo apt install python3-distutils` it works. However, for my case, I really need distutils placed in the virtualenv.

How can I include distutils in the virtual environment?

Comment: Python virtual environments can not be moved or renamed, they can not be used with a different Python interpreter (except same major and minor) than the one used to create it. -- What do you really want to do?

Comment: I would like to create a .deb that installs the virtual environment. I tried dh-virtualenv, but after a long time trying to make it work, I gave up. I thought that the easiest way would be to include an existent virtual env to the .deb, and put postinst instructions to paste in the target system.

Comment: Does it have to be `.deb`? Packaging Python applications is not the most straightforward thing, it depends a lot on the context. You could try [zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html)-based solutions such as [pex](https://pypi.org/project/pex/) or [shiv](https://pypi.org/project/shiv/). Also you could try something like [briefcase](https://pypi.org/project/briefcase/), [Nuitka](https://pypi.org/project/Nuitka/) or [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/).